# Android Studio - java.io.FileNotFoundException: (The system cannot find the file specified) and Could not extract JNI library

Tags: java, android, android-studio, flutter, gradle

I am a complete beginner to android development with flutter. I simply ran the default app in android studio using Flutter with a Samsung Android device connected, I get the following error

> `Could not extract native JNI library`
> `Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1`

Error in Android Studio

[image]

To debug on windows console I used

```
gradle test -info
```

I get the following output.

```
`> java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\LENOVO! (The system cannot find the file specified)`
```

These are my observations so far :

1. My `flutter doctor` is working perfectly fine.
2. I have downgraded my Java to Java 8.
3. My .dll file is not loading in .gradle/native/30/windows-amd64 folder. Only I can see is .dll.LOCK file

I dont understand where is the problem. Is it because of character I used like ''!'' in my user name of system ? Please help in contributing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue was in my path which had special characters (like !) in it.
Java gets messed up with special characters in it.